# Umlauts on Linux like on Mac, US Keyboard

Tags: linux, mac, keyboard, compose-key

I'd like to cut down on my keyboard Schizophrenia...

I work on a Mac at work and I can type Umlauts via Option+u, key

Example: Option+u (Release), a gives ä

On my home PC (Linux, Opensuse 12) I press Compose+", a.

I also type in Dvorak... so the Mac way of typing umlauts seems much much easier to my fingers.  Anyone know how to change the compose key sequences on Linux to change umlauts to Compose+u?

Thanks

-- Solution I used --

found this post: 
http://forums.freebsd.org/archive/index.php/t-28413.html

and I edited my xkb/us file as described BUT with dvorak keys:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "dev-de" {
name[Group1]= "USA - German developers";
include "us(dvorak)"
include "ctrl(nocaps)"

key <AC04> { [ u, U, udiaeresis, Udiaeresis ] };
key <AC02> { [ o, O, odiaeresis, Odiaeresis ] };
key <AC01> { [ a, A, adiaeresis, Adiaeresis ] };
key <AC10> { [ s, S, ssharp, S ] };

include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```

Now I can just do:

```
setxkbmap us dev-de
```

and type umlauts with ralt.  Äwesöme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using your compose key, what you want is to assign your *third level modifier* to a modifier key in Linux. This modifier works exactly the same as Mac OS X's option key, by default. I did this some time ago using Ubuntu and Mint, and if you're on KDE or Gnome, it should be easy to set up.

I assigned my third level modifier to my leftmost Meta key, as that's in a similar location as the Option key would be on a Mac keyboard.

To do this, go to your keyboard preferences and assign a key as your third level modifier.

Some pages that may help you with this are:

http://fsymbols.com/keyboard/linux/choosers/
http://www.bohemianalps.com/blog/2009/special-characters-in-linux/

The UI may have changed a bit, but if you know what you're looking for, you might find out how to assign it.

Comment: Ok, great answer. I didn't use this exact answer but it pointed me in the correct place.  Thanks!  See my edit in the question

Comment: That link is a 404 now.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to setup umlauts on my thinkpad keyboard with US layout (it works hehe `ßöäü€` and so on). I run Ubuntu 22.04 on it.

1. Use `xev` to determine the keycode of your <kbd>Right-Alt</kbd> key (for me it's 108 on a thinkpad p1 gen3)
2. Create a file `~/.Xmodmap` with contents:

   ```
   ! Map umlauts to PRINT SCREEN + 
   keycode 135 = Mode_switch
   keysym e = e E EuroSign
   keysym a = a A adiaeresis Adiaeresis
   keysym o = o O odiaeresis Odiaeresis
   keysym u = u U udiaeresis Udiaeresis
   keysym s = s S ssharp
   ```
3. Edit your `/home/user/.bashrc` file and add this line at the bottom:

   ```
   xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
   ```

You can also run this command in your current shell so you don't have to open a new shell.
Voila! :) Works!

I found a very good description [in this post](https://www.blunix.com/blog/using-german-umlauts-on-us-layout-keyboards.html)